# member registration using freemember

Tags: members, freemember

Using freemember to register a member with custom fields and when I submit a form intentionally with errors the appropriate inline errors are returned - that works as desired. When i submit the form with correct data the ugly EE error screen is output requiring all the custom member fields that were just submitted.

Any ideas?

Comment: To make this question more helpful to future searches it would be great if you could add the exact error message EE displays :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like you have the required = yes in the custom member field settings. IF you are using FreeMember it is best to leave those at not being required in the EE CP then requiring them with the required tag in your opening FreeMember tag.